# How to adjust Mylyn wikitext display appearance in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, formatting, markdown, mylyn-wikitext

I searched the web/stackoverflow for hours and could not find a solution...

I am using eclipse for C (2023-12) and have a few markdown files in my code that are meant to document the code components. The intent is to simply have the files as part of the code, no parsing or editing of markdown text during runtime of my code is intended.
In the preview tab of the editor the headings are all the same size, which makes navigating/reading the document very cumbersome. So I am looking for a way to change the appearance of the content of the preview tab.

What I found so far is that - contrary to eclipse docu - there is no preferences tab "appearance" under the "wikitext" preference item. In my workspace log I see errors of the type:
`!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.findNext: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.FindNextAction@324f600a)} vs {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.FindNextAction@324f600a)} in: PartImpl (org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor)  removeOnHide org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui.editor.markupEditorContext`

Does that error relate to the non-existance of that "appearance" prefeences tab?
Where else would I be able to change the preview appearance in the markdown editor?
Thanks a lot for any pointers!
Cheers

example markdown code (both headings display as same size, which is huge to start with):

```
# Custom Board Configuration

bla bla bla...

## Board peripherals

- Buttons
- SD Card
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNyVf.png)

Edit: yes, I meant the "preview" tab. code sampel provideded, too.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the display tab"_? The _Preview_ tab at the bottom of the editor? Could you please provide a Markdown example as text in your question (formatted as _Sample Code_) with which your issue can be reproduced along with a screenshot of what you see (be aware that there is an [alternate Markdown syntax for headings](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#alternate-syntax))? The  _Preview_ tab uses the browser widget which might differ depending which system you have.

Comment: The `Conflicting handlers` are not related to the appearance. Conflicting handlers means that somewhere (depending which UI element is focused) more than one handler for the same command exists which might causing a shortcut not or not correctly working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that only the font sizes used in the WikiText editor in the *Markdown Source* tab can be configured in the preferences *General > Editors > Text Editors > WikiText*.

In contrast, the **font sizes** used in the ***Preview* tab** seem to be **hard-coded** in the `org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui` plugin in the file `org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/wikitext/ui/viewer/default.css`: in line 138 the font size for **`h1` ... `h4`** is set to [**`font-size: 1.75em;`**](https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn/blob/aa83e9d59ba6b865596ec16394bb5b6c796ef2ed/mylyn.docs/wikitext/ui/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui/src/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/wikitext/ui/viewer/default.css#L138).

As workaround/hack you can replace in your Eclipse installation in  `plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui_*.jar` the file `org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/wikitext/ui/viewer/default.css` with your version.

Please consider to do a pull request with a better [`default.css`](https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn/blob/main/mylyn.docs/wikitext/ui/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui/src/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/wikitext/ui/viewer/default.css). It would also be nice to have a preference to customize it. The [default values for the *Markdown Source* tab can be found here](https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn/blob/aa83e9d59ba6b865596ec16394bb5b6c796ef2ed/mylyn.docs/wikitext/ui/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui/src/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/wikitext/ui/editor/preferences/Preferences.java#L103-L108).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately these preferences do not work in my eclipse. I tried by setting the h1 font size to 20%, restarted eclipse and got no change. What it does change is the apperance in the editor "markdown source" tab. That was not the intention though.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I have updated my answer and in contrast to the first time, I also verified it this time. ;)

Comment: thanks for the update! However on my system I do not find any file by the name `org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui_*.jar` or similar. The plugin is installed by eclipse as part of the standard installer. Where would I find the file in that case?

Comment: When you used the Eclipse Installer it will be in your user directory in `.p2/pool/plugins` (`*` in `org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui_*.jar` is the version).